# Web Services SoapException

Tags: c#, web-services

Getting the following error when trying to call my WebService method. It points to `pxy.AddCustomer(txtLogin.Text);` but I am confused about why I am getting this error and how to fix it.

I read in another response that it was happening because my Web Reference is to a Web Service in the solution and not to a published Web Service. But I am not sure how true this is because in the write up of our project, our professor tells us to do it this way until our project is ready to be published.

> An exception of type 'System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException' occurred in System.Web.Services.dll but was not handled in user code
>   Additional information: System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to process request. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server) ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The network path was not found

Web Services WebMethod:

```
    [WebMethod]
    public void AddCustomer(string Name)
    {
        SqlCommand objCommand = new SqlCommand();
        objCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        objCommand.CommandText = "AddCustomer";


        SqlParameter inputParameter = new SqlParameter("@theName", Name);
        DBConnect objDB = new DBConnect();
        objCommand.Parameters.Add(inputParameter);
        objDB.GetDataSetUsingCmdObj(objCommand);           

    }
```

Button Click:

```
protected void btnNewUser_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AuctionSvcPxy.AuctionService pxy = new AuctionSvcPxy.AuctionService();

        pxy.AddCustomer(txtLogin.Text);


        Session["Customer"] = txtLogin.Text.ToString();
        Response.Redirect("HomePage.aspx");

    }//end btnNewUser_Click
```

Connection calls:

```
public DBConnect()
    {
        myConnectionSql = new SqlConnection(SqlConnectString);
    }
```

Use this to connect, where SqlConnectString is the connection string with my username and password to connect
and

```
 public DataSet GetDataSetUsingCmdObj(SqlCommand theCommand)
    {
        theCommand.Connection = myConnectionSql;
        SqlDataAdapter myDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(theCommand);
        DataSet myDataSet = new DataSet();
        myDataAdapter.Fill(myDataSet);
        ds = myDataSet;

        return myDataSet;
    }
```

Comment: Where is the connection string for your SQL DB defined and how are you using it to open the connection?

Comment: edited my question to add what i call from another connection class library that I have

Comment: Can you connect to the db on the web service machine from the command-line?

Comment: Not really familiar with how to go about doing that. But I don't think the web service is connecting to the DB, because when I take out `DataSet myDataSet = objDB.GetDataSetUsingCmdObj(objCommand);` it doesn't crash anymore.

Comment: But I don't know why it isn't. Any suggestions?